# Melodyne Essential mistakenly interpreted two notes as one. Can I correct this?

Tags: vst, pitch

I'm trying out Melodyne Essential because of an ongoing Black Friday promo. Usually it detects the splits of the notes correctly, but it just had a goofup where it mistakenly interpreted two notes as the same note.

Is there a good way to manually nudge it to split the note without getting a more advanced version of Melodyne?

Answer (score 2):

There‘s a tab where you can set the algorithm. Usually setting it to „melody“ should fix this.